# phpmailer + multiple possible file uploads->attachments (i'm stuck)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, phpmailer

greetings fellow stackers,

**sorry in advance that this is so long!!!**

tho i've worked with php & js for years, i'm still a noob with writing my own code. for lack of funds to hire a developer, i've been given the task to create this online form for participants to fill out & upload files to.

eventually, the goal is to learn how to have the form submissions go into a mysql database & be able to render results out on screen. ***BUT***, for now, we are content to just have the form results emailed to us.

so far, i have created the html/css form needed, and i have implemented a way to submit the form via ajax/jquery to my phpmailer code, which then sends the results back to give the user feedback of success or error without a page refresh.

i *have been* successful in making this happen *withOUT* file uploads/attachments. and i *have been* successful in making this happen with *just 1* file upload/attachment.
but i ***have NOT*** been successful in making this happen with ***more than 1*** file uploads/attachments.

i know i'm missing some fundamental knowledge in php & js, but i've been trying to teach myself as i go with this project. i've read SO much and tried every suggestion/tutorial i've found in stackoverflow and other places via google'ing. but i'm just not "getting it" yet for some reason.

could really use some help & don't know where else to go to ask besides here. i should have asked weeks ago, but i kept making incremental progress in various other parts, i just thought that key would be right around the corner. but now i gotta have this done & can't waste any more time trying to figure it out like i have been. i pray for mercy ;-)

so, a tad more background/information in case it'll be helpful to know...

- the form page is html (no php in that page).
- i've got my links in the head to Jquery, Jquery.Easing, Jquery.Form,
  Jquery.Validate, Jquery.Validate.Additional.Methods, amongst a couple
  other i don't think are relevant to this.
- i'm using Jquery's Valdiate plugin for instant general validation.
- i've got PHP validation code for the file uploads as a fallback.
- we only care about modern browsers (no need for hacks or backwards
  compatibility).
- i'm using a Jquery plugin called EZDZ to have a drag'n'drop option
  for the file inputs (https://github.com/jaysalvat/ezdz).
- i've got the latest phpmailer files (class.phpmailer.php,
  class.smtp.php, & PHPMailerAutoload.php) from the github page
  (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
- i'm using a free Mandrill account (http://mandrill.com) to send the
  email thru - not because i really understand it or anything, but
  because it was suggested i do so when i couldn't get gmail to work
  with it.
- and lastly, the only form items that are "required" is the "name",
  "email", & the 1st file upload with its accompanying checkbox group.
  all the other file uploads, checkboxes, text inputs, etc are
  optional.

remember, i've gotten all this to work just fine without having a file attachment & with just having 1 file attachment. it's having the multiple options for file uploads that's throwing me off.

here is my form tag code (so you can see it, as i've seen in other posts some issues were caused here)...

```
<form name="cycleReports" id="cycleReports" class="cycleReports" action="/scripts/cycleReports-formProcessor.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on">
```

i have a grouping of checkboxes that stumped me for a while, but i finally was able to figure out how to deal with those by having empty brackets in the 'name' like `name="groupOfCheckboxes[]"` and then found some code to deal with that (below) which reads the "value" of each checkbox. but i read elsewhere that you can do that like this if you don't have a "value", like for file inputs...

```
<input type="file" name="cycleFile[cycleFileDocument1]" id="cycleFile-document1" class="cycleFile requireMe" />
<input type="file" name="cycleFile[cycleFileDocument2]" id="cycleFile-document2" class="cycleFile" />
<input type="file" name="cycleFile[cycleFileDocument3]" id="cycleFile-document3" class="cycleFile" />
<input type="file" name="cycleFile[cycleFileSupplement1]" id="cycleFile-supplemental1" class="cycleFile" />
<input type="file" name="cycleFile[cycleFileSupplement2]" id="cycleFile-supplemental2" class="cycleFile" />
<input type="file" name="cycleFile[cycleFileOther1]" id="cycleFile-other1" class="cycleFile" />
```

and, in case it's relevant, here's my submit button plus the 3 divs the js file uses to insert the notifications...

```
<button type="submit" name="button" id="submit" class="submit">Submit Form</button>
<div class="errorMsgs"></div>
<div id="noteFailure"></div>
<div id="noteSuccess"></div>
```

here's the majority of my JS/Ajax/Jquery file that provides validation & submission...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.validator.addClassRules("requireMe", {
        required: true,
        minlength: 1
    });

    $.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
        var param = 10485760;
        return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)    
    });

    $.validator.addClassRules("fileValidations", {
        filesize: true,
        extension: "pdf|txt|jpg|png|mp3",
        accept:    "application/pdf,"
                  +"text/plain,"
                  +"image/jpeg,"
                  +"image/png,"
                  +"audio/mpeg,"
                  +"audio/mp3,"
    });

    $('#cycleReports').validate({
        focusCleanup: true,
        focusInvalid: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        errorClass: "barf",
        validClass: "booyahh",

        errorPlacement: $.noop, // disable default messages
        errorLabelContainer: $("div.errorMsgs"),
        errorElement: 'p',

        rules: { 
            uploaderName: {
                required: true
            },
            uploaderEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            'cycleDoc1Type[]': {
                required: true,
            },
        },

        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            $(element).parents('div.formItem').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            $(element).parents('div.ezdz-dropzone').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        },

        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            $(element).parents('div.formItem').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            $(element).parents('div.ezdz-dropzone').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        },

        messages: {
            uploaderName: "Please specify your name.",
            uploaderEmail: {
                required: "We need your email address in case we have a question.",
                email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
            },
            'cycleDoc1Type[]': "A Cycle Document needs at least one check to identify it's kind.",
            cycleFileDocument1: "Only standard document filetypes under 10 MB's are acceptable.",
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) { // Use Ajax to send everything to the form Processor php file
            showAJAXLoader(); // config.progressbar.js
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({ // ajaxSubmit function submits the form without a page refresh to another URL.
                // Should the result be successful, call this function. 
                // After the submission, this function is called. 
                    // responseText is the text which is returned from the server. 
                    // statusText is the HTTP Status Code. 
                    // xhr is the XMLHttpRequest object used. 
                    // $form is the form element that was processed.
                success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                    var res = jQuery.parseJSON(responseText);
                        if(res.error){
                            hideAJAXLoader(); // config.progressbar.js
                            $("#noteFailure").html(res.msg).hide().slideDown("fast");
                                window.setTimeout(function(){
                                    $("#noteFailure").hide(500)
                                }, 8000);
                        }else{
                            hideAJAXLoader(); // config.progressbar.js
                            $(form).slideUp("fast"); // Now, after submission, if successful, sliding the form up only showing notification
                            $("#noteSuccess").html(res.msg).hide().slideDown("fast"); // This puts the return value of the AJAX call into the #response div.
                        } // END if/else
                  } // END success: function()
            }); // END ajaxSubmit
        return false; // This stops the form from normal submission.
        } // END submitHandler
    }); // END validate
}); // END function
```

okay, so, here are parts of my PHP file...

```
$return = array('error'=>0);

    $uploaderName =         $_POST['uploaderName']; // TEXT INPUT
    $uploaderEmail =        $_POST['uploaderEmail']; // TEXT INPUT
    $uploaderRole =         $_POST['uploaderRole']; // DROPDOWN SINGLE SELECTION
    $uploaderSchool =       $_POST['uploaderSchool']; // DROPDOWN SINGLE SELECTION

    $gradeRange =           $_POST['gradeRange']; // THIS IS A GROUP OF CHECKBOXES gradeRange[]
    $cycleSubject =         $_POST['cycleSubject']; // DROPDOWN SINGLE SELECTION
    $lessonTopic =      $_POST['lessonTopic']; // TEXT INPUT
    $pedagogicalFocus =     $_POST['pedagogicalFocus']; // DROPDOWN SINGLE SELECTION

    $cycleDoc1Type =        $_POST['cycleDoc1Type']; // THESE 4 ARE GROUPS OF CHECKBOXES THAT PERTAIN TO EACH OF THE 1ST 4 FILE UPLOADS
    $cycleDoc2Type =        $_POST['cycleDoc2Type'];
    $cycleDoc3Type =        $_POST['cycleDoc3Type'];
    $cycleDoc4Type =        $_POST['cycleDoc4Type'];

    $cycleDoc1OtherDesc =   $_POST['cycleDoc1OtherDesc']; // THESE 2 TEXT INPUTS PERTAIN TO THE LAST 2 FILE UPLOADS
    $cycleDoc2OtherDesc =   $_POST['cycleDoc2OtherDesc'];

    $cycleFile =            $_POST['cycleFile']; // THIS IS THE FILE INPUT FIELDS cycleFile[]
```

now, here is the code i have that **DOES work** if i only have 1 file input...

```
$allowedExts = array( "pdf", "txt", "jpg", "png", "mp3");

$allowedMimeTypes = array(
    'application/pdf',
    'text/plain',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/png',
    'audio/mpeg', 
    'audio/mp3',
    );

$temp = explode('.', $_FILES['uploaderFile']['name']);

$dest_file = '/home/vandytpeg/public_html/temp/' . time() . '-' . $_FILES['uploaderFile']['name'];

$extension = end($temp);

if (( $_FILES['uploaderFile']['size'] < 10485760) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {   // 5242880 bytes = 5MB, 10485760 = 10 MB, 52428800 = 50 MB

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaderFile']['tmp_name'], $dest_file);

} else { //execute if filesize is too large & if extension doesn't match accepted
    $return['error'] = 1;
    $return['msg'] =  "<span class='failure'>Only the specified file-type that are under 10 MB are allowed!";
}
```

...i took out the above code (for safe keeping) and am trying to morph it into something that works for potentially multiple files. and **here is where i'm stuck** mostly (i think). this is how far i've gotten after adding more than one file upload option. i'm not sure if any part of it is "correct" exactly. so i hope somebody can help me with this part (as well as the others)...

```
$numbFiles = count(array_filter($_FILES['cycleFile']['name']));

$allowedExts = array( "pdf", "txt", "jpg", "png", "mp3");

$allowedMimeTypes = array(
    'application/pdf',
    'text/plain',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/png',
    'audio/mpeg', 
    'audio/mp3',
    );

$temp = explode('.', $_FILES['cycleFile']['name']);

$extension = end($temp);

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME); //??? NOT SURE IF THIS IS RIGHT OR NOT

$mime = $finfo->file($_FILES['cycleFile']['tmp_name']);  

for ($i = 0; $i < $numbFiles; ++$i) {

    $dest_file = '/home/vandytpeg/public_html/temp/' . time() . '-' . $_FILES['cycleFile']['name'][$i];

    if (in_array($mime, $allowedMimeTypes) 
        && filesize($_FILES['cycleFile']['size'] < 10485760)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cycleFile']['tmp_name'][$i], $dest_file);

    } else { //execute if does not validate
        $return['error'] = 1;
        $return['msg'] =  "<span class='failure'>MAMMAMIA Only the specified file-type that are under 10 MB are allowed!";
    }   
}
```

here is the start of the email preparation section (just so you see i have the required phpmailer stuff in there)...

```
if(!$return['error']){  

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->isHTML(true);
```

...after that i have the Mandril HOST, PORT, SMTPAuth, USR, PWD, stuff, plus the SETFROM, ADDADDRESS, & SUBJECT email header stuff.

then i have the form items laid out in the html email like this (here's just one to show as an example)...

```
$mail->Body  = "<p><strong>Uploader's Name:</strong><br />";
$mail->Body .= $uploaderName;
$mail->Body .= "</p>";
```

...and i have the plain text version for each duplicated later but with `$mail->AltBody` instead.

now, here is the code for that grouping of checkboxes i mentioned earlier that had me stumped for a long time. i finally figured this out from various other postings (went back'n'forth between isset & empty etc; i don't really understand the difference or what "set" means, but this one seems to work). tho not "*necessary*", it would be nice to figure out how to *NOT* have a trailing comma after the last checked selection or if there's only 1...

```
$mail->Body .= "<p><strong>Grade Range:</strong><br />";
if (isset($gradeRange))
    { 
    foreach($gradeRange as $gradeRangeValue)
        { 
          $mail->Body .= $gradeRangeValue .", "; // HOW TO NOT HAVE A COMMA AFTER THE LAST OPTION NOR IF ONLY ONE OPTION THAT WAS CHECKED?
        } 
    //unset($value); // IS THIS NEEDED? SEEMS TO WORK WITHOUT IT
    } 
else 
    {
    $mail->Body .= ""; // If no options selected, leave blank
    };
```

under that, i need to show the checkbox options selected for the first required file upload as well as for the subsequent 3 IF they exist. i borrowed the code used for the big checkbox group above. but where **i'm stuck** here (i think) is **how to** have the filename of the attached file listed for reference. i'll only paste in the first two here to save space. i believe i could apply whatever the solution would be to the rest afterwards...

```
$mail->Body .= "<p><strong>Checked Option(s) of 1st Attached File (". $dest_file[$i] ."):</strong><br />"; // HOW TO LIST THE FILE NAME HERE?
if (isset($cycleDoc1Type)) { // THIS IS THE 4 CHECKBOXES PERTAINING TO THE FIRST SPECIFIC FILE
  foreach($cycleDoc1Type as $cycleDoc1Type_Cked) { 
       $mail->Body .= $cycleDoc1Type_Cked .", "; }} else { $mail->Body .= ""; }; // USING SAME PATTERN AS FOR GRADERANGE
$mail->Body .= "</p>";
$mail->Body .= "<p><strong>Checked Option(s) if 2nd Attached File (". $dest_file[$i] ."):</strong><br />";
if (isset($cycleDoc2Type)) { 
  foreach($cycleDoc2Type as $cycleDoc2Type_Cked) { 
       $mail->Body .= $cycleDoc2Type_Cked .", "; }} else { $mail->Body .= ""; };    
$mail->Body .= "</p>";
```

and then, for the part that does the actual attaching of whatever files were uploaded...

```
$mail->AddAttachment($dest_file);
```

...that's the code that works *if* there's only 1 file upload to attach. i **can't figure out** how to do it for *any* file that was attached. i've got 2 running theories thus far in my investigation...

```
    foreach($numbFiles as $dest_file)
    {
        $mail->AddAttachment($dest_file);
    }
////// or ????
    if (isset($cycleFile))
        { 
        foreach($numbFiles as $dest_file)
            { 
            $mail->AddAttachment .= ": ". $dest_file ." :";
            } 
        } 
    else 
        {
        $mail->AddAttachment .= "";
        }
```

and lastly, for the moment of truth, the send mail & send info back to the js->html page for notification (this part does work, as i've mentioned, if sending without file or with just 1 file, but not with multiple)...

```
    if(!$mail->Send()) {

        $return['error'] = 1;
        $return['msg'] = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;   // ErrorInfo holds the most recent mailer error message

     } else {

            $return['msg'] = "<span class='success'>Success! Your Cycle Report has been sent."; // THIS IS THE GREEN SUCCESS MESSAGE

            //unlink($dest_file); // NOT SURE IF THIS IS NEEDED ANYMORE DUE TO USING "move_uploaded_file" ABOVE
            }

} // closes: if(!$return['error']){ 


echo json_encode($return); 
die();
```

the only error i'm getting is in the javascript browser console, which is very cryptic (to me). other times there's no error there but still the form hangs.

what's weird now is, with this code, if i try to send without uploading a file (if i disable the "required" on it), the html page sticks after pressing submit with just the js spinner. but the email actually does come thru. if i do try to upload a file, the same thing happens but i get no email.

so, i know i'm missing the appropriate code to show me errors & where it's hanging. that's yet another part i haven't learned yet.

i know this is LONG (understatement?); just didn't know how to provide all the needed information otherwise.
so if you've made it this far & can help, would be very grateful.

***attempt at a summary***

**PRIORITY...**

- to get *this* to work with 1 required but multiple possible file inputs that uploads the file(s), sends it/them as attachments in the email, & to then delete them off the server.

**DESIRES...**

- to render comma's between checkbox selections in the email but not after the last selection nor if there's only one.
- to render the filename of each attachment in the body of the email.

btw: i 'might' be willing/able to pay for a weekly tutor/coach to help me learn javascript/jquery (1st). something to think about :-)

PS: PLEASE don't assume i should know things, so please don't be cryptic or short in your answers. THANKS!!!

Comment: You need to separate out your problems and solve them individually, then join them together. Solve file uploads (PHP docs cover this perfectly), then look at sending email (PHPMailer docs), then look at storing stuff in your DB. This question is way too complicated to be answered sensibly.

Comment: @Synchro thanks for your comment; but that's what i did. i just included all this for reference to try & help whoever knows how to do this narrow down where the issue(s) would be. i've seen other posts where the OP did _not_ do this and there was a lot of needless back'n'forth. i'd like to avoid needless back'n'forth if possible. the multiple file uploads issue is **the main issue**, and i _have_ read thru the PHP docs; but am just not able (so far) to figure it out.